# How to update a running CoroutineWorker?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I have a `CoroutineWorker` worker that uploads files to server. I want to be able to pause it and resume it when user clicks on button without closing the Worker. I read that one can use the `updateWork()` method, but I don't see any examples for that. Can someone show me how to use it?